# How to groupby time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below,column B's dtype is datetime64.

```
    A      B
0   a   2016-09-13
1   b   2016-09-14
2   b   2016-09-15
3   a   2016-10-13
4   a   2016-10-14
```

I would like to groupby according to month(or in general year and day...)

so I would like to get count result  below, key = column B.

```
              a       b
2016-09       1       2
2016-10       2       0
```

I tried groupby. but I couldn't figure out how to handle dtypes like datetime64... 
How can I handle and group dtype datetime64?

Comment: IIUC then `df.groupby([df['B'].dt.year, df['B'].dt.day])['A'].size()` should work

Comment: @EdChum First, IINM, you meant `df.groupby([df.B.dt.year, df.A]).size().unstack()`; second, it doesn't work - it needs the combination of year and month.

Comment: @AmiTavory the OP had mentioned they wanted `or in general year and day` so I was answering that query, I didn't test my code snippet so it was a punt

Comment: @EdChum Please don't get me wrong - you're one of the most careful answerers (and a comment is indeed just a comment). Just wanted to point that out. All the best.

Comment: @AmiTavory I don't take any offence at being corrected, I'm just explaining why I was offering a probable solution to a part of the question, +1 for your answer

Comment: @EdChum Thanks, and all the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you start with

```
In [247]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'B': ['2016-09-13', '2016-09-14', '2016-09-15', '2016-10-13', '2016-10-14']})

In [248]: df.B = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
```

Then you can `groupby`-`size`, then `unstack`:

```
In [249]: df = df.groupby([df.B.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.B.dt.month.astype(str), df.A]).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Finally, you just need to make `B` a date again:

```
In [250]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

In [251]: df
Out[251]: 
A           a  b
B               
2016-10-01  2  0
2016-09-01  1  2
```

Note that the final conversion to a date-time set a uniform day (you can't have a "dayless" object of this type).

Comment: Perfect answer, but instead of doing the difficult date groupby conversion you can simply do this: df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('M'), 'A']).size().unstack().fillna(0)

Comment: @Skirrebattie Thanks! Also, your way looks more promising. Unfortunately, a copy-paste of it gave me `Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`. If you could get it to work on a full example, I think you should post it as an answer in itself, because it does look simpler.

Comment: will do, but it's basically the same. But for clarity sake will add it.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the index to the datetime you can use pd.TimeGrouper to sort by various time ranges. Example code:

```
# recreate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'B': ['2016-09-13', '2016-09-14', '2016-09-15',
                                                        '2016-10-13', '2016-10-14']})
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

# set column B as index for use of TimeGrouper
df.set_index('B', inplace=True)

# Now do the magic of Ami Tavory's answer combined with timeGrouper:
df = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('M'), 'A']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

This returns:

```
A             a    b
B                   
2016-09-30  1.0  2.0
2016-10-31  2.0  0.0
```

or alternatively (credits to ayhan) skip the setting to index step and use the following one-liner straight after creating the dataframe:

```
# recreate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'B': ['2016-09-13', '2016-09-14', '2016-09-15',
                                                        '2016-10-13', '2016-10-14']})
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='B', freq='M'), 'A']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

which returns the same answer

Comment: Nice use of `TimeGrouper`.

Comment: You can also do `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='B', freq='M'), 'A']).size().unstack().fillna(0)` That doesn't require to set column B as the index.